# what options are there for synching two dirs on diff Windows servers?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have two servers, one is a primary and the other is a backup. There is dir in the primary server I'd like to sync with the backup server. What are my options for doing this??? I am not aware of any tool, either from Microsoft or 3rd party. I've been thinking of putting together a Java service to do this, but perhaps there is something better out there????

Regards,

Rafael

Answer (score 4):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), from Microsoft, works well.  It's available in the [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en).

Comment: +1 for robocopy, I blogged about it recently: http://improve.dk/blog/2009/10/07/simple-file-synchronization-using-robocopy

Comment: The main drawback to robocopy for me is that the bandwidth throttling is rubbish.  This makes it unusable in a production environment for any large copy.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do a syncronisation powertoy called [Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52)

There are also lots of 3rd party ones. [ViceVersa](http://www.tgrmn.com/web/file_synchronization.htm) is one that I've used before and would reccomend.

Comment: I've also used ViceVersa previously but it has a number of limitations that you'll run into if you sync large directories & files - check my blog post in another comment for details. Unless you need some of the more advanced VV features, Robocopy is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Robocopy is simple to use if you are doing a simple sync.  Its not at all simple when you are stringing together a load of options on the commandline rather than seeing exactly what will be done in a handy gui. Each has its own use.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html) a try, will do exactly what you want.